# Unique IDs using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, unique-key

Can any one tell me how can I create unique ID?  For example:

```
Account id 9845673333
Account id 9845673334
Account id 9845673335
Account id 9845673336
```

Comment: You don't create it .. It is a sequence on the database server.  Everytime you insert it increments.

Comment: You can create it if you don't want auto-incrementing ID's.

Comment: Use an autoincrementing int PK in your database. Problem solved.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a stored integer value starting from 1, and increment it each time you need to issue a new account id.

Then, it will always be unique.

Comment: Likely to be fraught with race conditions and possible blocking.